# How to add missing columns and ignoring existing columns in ms access dbase with vb.net?

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2012

The scenario is this. I have an existing ms access database. Inside the database has Table1. Assuming that I do not know what columns or existing columns are there already. My program using vb.net form, in just one click of a button I can add all columns like name, salary, address, daterec, and updated. No problem in there adding all those columns since they are not existing in Table1. My problem is in some databases Table1, some columns/fields are already exist like salary and address, I want to add columns name, daterec and updated but it gave me an error **"Field 'name' already exists in Table 'Table1'**. 
What should I do? I just want to add those columns who are not yet existing in Table1. I want to ignore those existing columns and proceed adding those missing columns. Any suggestions are very much appreciated.

Below is the code that can add columns and for modification. Thank you.

```
Dim ConnString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|addcolumn.accdb"


    Dim SqlString As String = "ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD COLUMN " + "name Text(250)," + "salary Number," + "address Memo," + "daterec DateTime," + "updated YesNo" 'Datatypes: Text is ShortText, Number is Number(Double), Memo is LongText, DateTime is Date or/and Time, YesNo is either checkbox/True or False/On or Off depends in saving format .
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(ConnString)
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn)
            conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
```

Comment: The `GetSchema` or `GetOleDbSchemaTable` methods of your connection object can provide information about schema, including columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't going to provide an answer because I didn't think that the question showed enough effort but, as the accepted answer was not what I would consider advisable, I felt I needed to. This code does what I have advised here and for the same question elsewhere and should work as is, although I've only tested with different file, table and column names.

```vb
Dim tableName = "Table1"

Using connection As New OleDbConnection($"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\addcolumn.accdb")
    connection.Open()

    'Get a DataTable containing information about all columns in the specified table.
    Dim schemaTable = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns,
                                                     {Nothing, Nothing, tableName})

    'Create a list of all new column names and data types to add.
    Dim dataTypesByColumnName As New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {{"name", "Text(250)"},
                                                                         {"salary", "Number"},
                                                                         {"address", "Memo"},
                                                                         {"daterec", "DateTime"},
                                                                         {"updated", "YesNo"}}

    'Get a list of the column names already in the table.
    Dim existingColumnNames = schemaTable.AsEnumerable().
                                          Select(Function(row) row.Field(Of String)("COLUMN_NAME")).
                                          ToArray()

    'Create a list of column definition snippets to insert into SQL code, e.g. "columnName DataType".
    Dim columnSnippets = dataTypesByColumnName.Keys.Except(existingColumnNames).
                                                    Select(Function(key) String.Format("{0} {1}", key, dataTypesByColumnName(key))).
                                                    ToArray()

    If columnSnippets.Any() Then
        'Construct the full SQL statement.
        Dim sql = String.Format("ALTER TABLE {0} ADD COLUMN {1}", tableName, String.Join(", ", columnSnippets))

        Dim command As New OleDbCommand(sql, connection)

        'Execute the single SQL statement against the database.
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If
End Using
```

It gets a list of existing columns from the database, excludes those from the list to be added and then adds the rest with a single SQL statement.

Comment: And if one of the columns to add fails, then which one failed? It it not all that bad of an idea to add column by column, since this breaks the problem down into discrete operations. The result is code that will add columns that can be added, and only the failure points need be addressed. This has quite a few advantages in debugging code, or isolation of which part failed.  So, I would not say "bad" here, but "different", and there are a number of advantages to using discrete operations against the table.  Its probably  better to update in one go, but it not a all or nothing proposition here.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal, I can't agree with that at all. Doing it column by column in testing is one thing. Doing it that way in Production is something else entirely. The code already ensure that no duplicate columns can be added, unless someone else slips in during the split second between the two database operations. If anything else specific to a column goes wrong then it's because you have written bad code in the first place, e.g. misspelled a data type. That's not something that should get through to that stage. If you don't build tables one column at a time, why would you edit them that way?

Comment: Comes down how often we add one column, not that we don't. Adding one column occurs during a typical table lifecycle. I agreed updating columns in one go is better. However advantages exist in adding column by column. We actually experienced that advantage is this example! All code is not perfect and a bad column names WAS used here (compiler not catching that). Modern approaches from objects, subs, local vars etc. seek to reduce and isolate parts of the code. That is what occurred here.  An advantage is a an advantage - can't ignore this! Is this advantage better then 1 update? Hard to say?

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal, no, not hard to say at all. If there's a bad column name then that would be found during testing. Once that's addressed, there's no point to putting testing code in your Production application. I won't argue any more because I suspect that you're just making excuses for suggesting a bad solution and, if you're not, then you're just providing a bad solution without excuses, which may be worse.

Comment: Sorry, you making straw arguments ,and  they not holding up. You claimed that no one adds a single column to a table. I not only stated that is often occurs, but THE actual poster in this question stated that only 1 column might be missing! So, don't try and spin a narrative that only one column is never added when clearly that is the case and in fact the actual poster in this thread stated this could occur! And yes, the one bad column can be found during testing and MY point was the code I posted makes that 1 bad column easier to find - even during testing.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal, you are mischaracterising what the OP said. The situation described sounds more like an upgrade process where v1 to v2 adds some columns and v2 to v3 adds more, so upgrading to v3 might have to add all columns to a v1 database or just some columns to a v2 database. Testing is good but you write Production code on the assumption that all the testing has been done. You don't need to include testing code in Production applications unless you are a bad developer who doesn't test properly before release. Oh, now I get it. As you were.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal, I've been a bit snarky but I mean what I say about not allowing for things in Production code that should already have been tested prior. the first thing I did when writing this code was put the schema table into a grid to see what it contained but that doesn't go into the final code. There should be no need to, for instance, allow for invalid column names or data types because that should already have been accounted for in the testing phase. Adding columns directly in Access will tell you what names are invalid so no code required for that.

Answer (score 0):

The challenge here is that as you note?
Some fields might exist, some might not.
So, you have to test + add on a field by field basis

Something like this should work:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim strCon As String
    strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Test\test44.accdb"

    Using dbCon As New OleDbConnection(strCon)
        dbCon.Open()
        AddFieldExist("table1", "name", "Text(250)", dbCon)
        AddFieldExist("table1", "Salary", "number", dbCon)
        AddFieldExist("table1", "Address", "memo", dbCon)
        AddFieldExist("table1", "Address", "memo", dbCon)
        AddFieldExist("table1", "DateRec", "datetime", dbCon)
        AddFieldExist("table1", "Upated", "YesNo", dbCon)

    End Using

End Sub

Sub AddFieldExist(strTable As String,
                    strField As String,
                    strType As String,
                    dbCon As OleDb.OleDbConnection)

    ' return true/false if field exist.

    Dim tblDef As New DataTable
    Dim oReader As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM " & strTable, dbCon)
    oReader.Fill(tblDef)

    If tblDef.Columns.IndexOf(strField) = -1 Then
        ' add field
        Dim strSQL As String = "ALTER TABLE " & strTable & " ADD COLUMN " & strField & " " & strType
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, dbCon)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If

End Sub
```

the code does assume that the table in question does have data. If it does not then you might have to introduce getSchema here, but for now, the above is quite much what I would suggest.

Comment: Thanks for your help buddy but it did not work. Same error prompted. Field 'name' already exists in table 'Table1'. Any modification please.

Comment: @AlbertKallal Why if I delete "name" it proceeds adding some columns but if it still there the columns are not adding? I think the "name" is the one that is recognized that if it is existing you cannot add columns.

Comment: @AlbertKallal Thanks my friend. I just put "On error Resume Next" and replacing column "name" with "fullname". Finally it works.

Comment: *"you have to test + add on a field by field basis"*. No you absolutely do not have to do that. That's a terrible way to do it. What you would actually do is determine what columns already exist first and then construct a single SQL statement to add all new columns but those.

Comment: @RonskyPis-an, any code that contains `On Error Resume Next` is bad code so any "solution" that requires that is not really a solution.

Comment: Sure, you still must test on a field by field bases. So, I was talking about the testing part for the field - the add can be done in one shot, but not the testing part!!  Even the other answer does this! What of course is different is THEN the act of adding those missing columns. So, is it a good idea to write some extra code or change it to add all missing columns in one shot? Sure, but then again this is not a high volume operation, and it not going to occur all that much. Un-like SQL server, the user will need exclusive use of the database for ANY solution that modifies the table structure.

Comment: Name for a field column is a reserved word - so it looks like using a different name was the fix - not the error handling (or lack of). But, to be fair? Neither of the solutions here have any error handling, so it hard to make a case for not adding some form of error handling - even resume next given that neither solutions have error handling. If we going to dock marks for no error handling, then both solutions fail in that regards.  but, note how the user was able to "easy" isolate which column did not work - so that field by field adding here quite much saved the day here - did it not?

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal, the OP didn't ask how to test their code. Proper testing technique is a subject all its own. If someone asks how to perform a task, they're not asking how to test unless they actually ask how to test. What exactly are you testing here? They already said that it works if there are no duplicates so the only issue being asked about here is handling duplicates so there's no good reason to add one column at a time for that reason. Other possible issues should already have been tested for and are not part of this question, so you're supposedly answering a question that wasn't asked.